# Как вывести строку из массива, имеющее определенную букву.c++

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, struct

Есть структура student (поля: Фамилия, Имя, Группу). Необходимо вывести тех студентов, у которых в фамилии есть буква "о", а в имени буквы "о" нет.
Сделал такой код, но понимаю что это полный бред)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>

struct student
{   
    std::string LastName;
    std::string FirstName;
    int group;
};
int main()
{   
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    using namespace std;
    int n=5;

    student * st = new student[n];
    for (int i = 0; i!= n; i++)
    {   
        cout << "Введите Фамилию студента" << endl;
        cin >> st[i].LastName;
        cout << "Введите Имя студента" << endl;
        cin >> st[i].FirstName;
        cout << "Номер группы" << endl;
        cin >> st[i].group;
        for (int j = 0; j != n; j++)
        {

            if (st[i].LastName == "о"  and st[i].FirstName != "о")
            {
                cout << st[i].LastName << " " << st[i].FirstName << " " << st[i].group << "\n";
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: из вопроса так и не понятно в чем проблема

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вопрос в том, как определить, у кого с `o` в порядке :), а у кого нет - то попробуйте заменить

```
st[i].LastName == "о" and st[i].FirstName != "о"
```

на

```
(st[i].LastName.find('o') != string::npos) && (st[i].FirstName.find('o') == string::npos)
```

Вы в своем коде *сравниваете строку*, а не проверяете наличие буквы.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, условие работает только когда буквы в кавычках англ. Это можно как то исправить?

Comment: Это отдельный [большой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/459154/195342).