# Программа выдаёт ошибку: "std::bad_alloc"

Tags: c++, строки, память

Функция `res()` должна на вход принимать `указатель на строку` и возращать `вектор с типом строки` с размером длины передаваемой строки, а каждый элемент в векторе должен соответственно равен каждому символу строки.

Проблема: При запуске программа выдаёт следующую **ошибку**:

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc`

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

vector<string> res(string *p) {
    vector<string> vres;
    vres.reserve(p->size());
    for (int i = 0; i < p->size();++i) {
        vres.push_back(p[i]);
    }
    return vres;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string word = "Hello";
    string * pword = &word;

    vector<string>result = res(pword);
    copy(result.begin(), result.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, " "));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Стоп-стоп!

```
p->size()
```

даст вам размер *строки*, а именно - 5. А дальше вы пытаетесь обращаться к несуществующим строкам `p[i]` (рассматривая `p` как *массив* строк, который на самом деле является просто указателем на *одну* строку) - есть ведь реально только одна строка - `p[0]`, а остальное - указатели не пойми куда!

Если вы поясните, что вы *хотели**, будет можно посоветовать, как это сделать...

Если уж позарез именно вектор строк - то вот так лучше:

```
vector<string> res(const string& p) {
    vector<string> vres;
    vres.reserve(p.size());
    for(auto c: p) vres.emplace_back(1,с);
    return vres;
}
```

Только вот то же результат легко получить без вектора вообще:

```
int main()
{
    string word = "Hello";
    copy(word.begin(), word.end(), ostream_iterator<char>(cout, " "));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я хочу реализовать что-то похожее на функцию split() из Python

Comment: То есть на вход ф-я принимает строку, а на выходе вектор, у которого каждый элемент соответственно равен каждому символу заданной строки

Comment: Напомни, а у строк `size` и `length` - одно и то же? Или `size` и `capacity`?

Comment: Тогда вам нужен скорее `vector<char>`. Но все то, что умеет `vector<char>`, умеет и `string` - просто нет никакого смысла в таком представлении...

Comment: @lakvak, `vres.push_back(string() + (*p)[i]);`

Comment: @Qwertiy https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size

Comment: @Qwertiy Можете объяснить, почему вы добавили string()? И что он делает?

Comment: p.s. Этот способ `vres.push_back(string() + (*p)[i]);` помог

Comment: @lakvak, он создаёт новую пустую строку. Кстати, лучше создать один раз и использовать через переменную. Это я так char в string скастил.

Comment: @Harry, о, классный вариант :) Я забыл, что у строки есть такой конструктор.

Comment: @Qwertiy Это из серии "зачем просто, если можно сложно". Не надо вообще передавать указатель, достаточно константной ссылки... https://ideone.com/yBiR2r

Comment: @Harry, да с указателем понятно, просто я написал, как конкретную строку заменить, если остальное не трогать. А вот ни про emplace_back, ни про конструктор с числом повторов символа я не вспомнил.

Comment: @Qwertiy Да эта функция - вообще лишняя сущность... Ведь `string` по сути не сто иное как вектор `char`ов.

Comment: @Harry Гениально! Но хотелось бы дальше с этим вектором работать

Comment: @Harry, ну может он упростил или ещё не закончил пример, а реально ему надо будет на слова разбить или по какому-то разделителю.

Comment: Ну работайте, без вопросов... Я же код привел в вопросе, как сделать вектор строк.

Comment: @Harry Обнаружил проблему: при вводе строки с русскими буквами, выводит следующие: � � � � � � � � � � � �   � � � � � �

Comment: Это отдельный большой вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8