# Создаю программу замены букв, запускается, но работает не верно! Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так? С++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

Учу C++. Загорелся идеей написать программу, что бы русский переводила в транслит, ну или хотя бы просто переводила в верхний регистр весь текст, причем, что бы на каждую букву внимание обращала и переводила в транслит или (на данном этапе в верхний регистр) Ну просто такая тренировка для мозга х) и ничего у меня не вышло. Программа запускается. Работает. Но в вывод в консоли выдаёт дичь!
Подскажите, что я делаю не так?
Код, который я накатал:

```
//да прибудет со мной сила...
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    char alphabetRus[33] = {'а','б','в','г','д','е','ё','ж','з','и','й','к','л','м','н','о','п','р','с','т','у','ф','х','ц','ч','ш','щ','ъ','ы','ь','э','ю','я'};
    char alphabetRusBig[33] = {'А','Б','В','Г','Д','Е','Ё','Ж','З','И','Й','К','Л','М','Н','О','П','Р','С','Т','У','Ф','Х','Ц','Ч','Ш','Щ','Ъ','Ы','Ь','Э','Ю','Я'};
    string vvod; // для пользовательского ввода
    int z; // для приёма локации буквы
    cout << "\n\n\t\t\t\tЗдравствуйте, это чисто тестовая прога для замены букв."<<endl;
    cout << "\nВведите пожалуйста фразу, буквы в которой так необходимо заменить.\n" << endl;
    cout << "Ваша фраза:";
    cin >> vvod;
    cout << "\nобщее число символов входящих в ведённую Вами строку составляет: " << vvod.size() <<" символов\n\n"<< endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 33; ++i)
    {
        z = vvod.find(alphabetRus[i]);
        vvod[z] = alphabetRusBig[i];
    }
    cout << "\nвведённая Вами фраза переведена в высокий регистр." << endl;
    cout << "\nТеперь она выглядит вот так: " <<vvod<<"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

А начинаю вводить не одно слово, а именно фразу - он видит только первое слово, во всяком случае если верить функции .size() из ряда функций объекта string.
я прям спецом вставил её в код ради этого (что бы отследить одну из проблем, но вот как решить не знаю).

Comment: https://ideone.com/yku9X2

Comment: Какой компилятор вы используете? 
У меня не заработало. Кракозябры выдало.
(У меня Microsoft Visual Studio 2019)  
Я кроме стандартных библиотек  с другими не работал))) я вроде и понимаю код, а вроде написан не знакомыми мне операторами)
#include <map>
#include <codecvt>
#include <locale>
Эти библиотеки вообще не знакомы мне))) ... пока-что)

Comment: Использую - онлайн компилятор. только что попробовал Clang 10.0.0 - все норм - https://wandbox.org/permlink/RR29d8ILiMokDPzF

Comment: "Новый код" - есть возможность на примере разобраться, подучиться)

Comment: крутой этот онлайн компилятор. Я уже и  mingw установил
и с другого сайта gcc (хотя я так понял та же самая хрень) установил. Ничего не спасает. а онлайн компиль - сделал.
Пока писал этот коммент - посмотрел чем именно компилил сайт. Clang 10.0. Ща буду учиться его скачивать, устанавливать на своём компе и юзать =_=
И если заработает - я обещаю, что выучу эти библиотеки хДД)

Comment: Хорошая связка, если под винду - QtCreator (в качестве ide) + MSYS2. Но конечно же нужно сперва поискать инфу в сети.

Comment: Маджесто, привет ещё раз, я пробовал и gcc и Кланг (с помощью которого, как сайт говорит, компилировалось). Ни в какую. У меня выдаёт кракозябры и всё тут. Читал на сайтах и про то, что нужно перевести в кодировку UTF-8 саму IDE, но вроде бы итак (может не там смотрел, я уже просто не знаю что делать!) Очень прошу помочь разобраться с проблемой! Не выходит скомпилировать без знаков вопроса вместо текста!, может можно с вами связаться как нибудь, показать как и что я делаю, может вы найдёте ошибку!

Comment: skype: majestio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Почему выдает каракули? Проблема локазализации

Подключите `#include <windows.h>` (если у вас ОС Windows, конечно) и в самом `int main ()` пропишите

```
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
```

В моем случае это часто помогало решить проблему локализации. После этого ваша программа у меня заработала. Если не поможет: [вот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8)

2. Ошибка в строчке `z = vvod.find(alphabetRus[i]);`

Вы ищите какую либо букву в алфавите и сравниваете с тем, что ввел пользователь. Однако вы неучли случай, когда программа не находит в введенном слове буквы. функция `find()` в таком случае выдает `string::npos` (константа обозначающая что, искомая подстрока не найдена и равна она `-1`).

Пример:

Пользователь ввел: `привет`

Алгоритм в начале `i = 0`: `vvod.find(alphabetRus[0]);`, что тоже самое `vvod.find('a');`. Однако такой буквы нет и функция `find()` выдает `-1`. Но потом ваш алгоритм говорит следующее: `vvod[-1] = alphabetRusBig[i];`, но как обратится к -1 элементу? :)

Так что, чтобы миновать данную ошибку:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 33; ++i)
    {
        z = vvod.find(alphabetRus[i]);
        if(z != string::npos)
           vvod[z] = alphabetRusBig[i];
    }
```

Итоговый код будет выглядеть так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251); //локализация
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    char alphabetRus[33] = { 'а','б','в','г','д','е','ё','ж','з','и','й','к','л','м','н','о','п','р','с','т','у','ф','х','ц','ч','ш','щ','ъ','ы','ь','э','ю','я' };
    char alphabetRusBig[33] = { 'А','Б','В','Г','Д','Е','Ё','Ж','З','И','Й','К','Л','М','Н','О','П','Р','С','Т','У','Ф','Х','Ц','Ч','Ш','Щ','Ъ','Ы','Ь','Э','Ю','Я' };
    string vvod; // для пользовательского ввода
    int z; // для приёма локации буквы
    cout << "\n\n\t\t\t\tЗдравствуйте, это чисто тестовая прога для замены букв." << endl;
    cout << "\nВведите пожалуйста фразу, буквы в которой так необходимо заменить.\n" << endl;
    cout << "Ваша фраза:";
    cin >> vvod;
    cout << "\nобщее число символов входящих в ведённую Вами строку составляет: " << vvod.size() << " символов\n\n" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 33; ++i)
    {
        z = vvod.find(alphabetRus[i]);
        if (z != string::npos) //проверка на то что символ нашелся
            vvod[z] = alphabetRusBig[i];
    }
    cout << "\nвведённая Вами фраза переведена в высокий регистр." << endl;
    cout << "\nТеперь она выглядит вот так: " << vvod << "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Кстати еще как решение вашей задачи можно использовать функции `toupper()` - перевод в верхний регистр и `tolower()` - перевод в нижний регистр. Обе эти функции из библиотеки cctype. (`#include <cctype>`)