# Проблема с выводом кирилицы с libzip

Tags: c++

Мне нужно открыть ZIP архив, затем найти в нём файл, и вывести содержимое этого файла(файл .txt). Для этого я нашел пример этого который работает с библиотекой libzip. Но когда я запускаю эту программу, то символы английской раскладки выводятся нормально, а вот символы кирилицы выводятся каким то набором символов. Подскажите пожалуйста что можно сделать в этой ситуации.

Код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <zip.h>
#include <locale.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
    //Open the ZIP archive
    int err = 0;
    zip* z = zip_open("file.zip", 0, &err);

    //Search for the file of given name
    const char* name = "text.txt";
    struct zip_stat st;
    zip_stat_init(&st);
    zip_stat(z, name, 0, &st);

    //Alloc memory for its uncompressed contents
    char* contents = new char[st.size];

    //Read the compressed file
    zip_file* f = zip_fopen(z, name, 0);
    zip_fread(f, contents, st.size);
    zip_fclose(f);

    //And close the archive
    zip_close(z);
    cout << contents;
    //Do something with the contents
    //delete allocated memory
    delete[] contents;
}
```

Comment: а как именно выглядит кириллический текст? может там utf-8 в файле.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Русский язык в консоли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/%d0%a0%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8)

Comment: Он выглядит вот так: Р-С'Р? С?С?С?С?РєР°С? С?Р°С?РєР>Р°Р?РєР°(Там написано: Это русская раскладка) It is a textээээ  (ээээ - оно всегда почему то добавляет в конец).

Comment: Насчет сout, у меня кирилица отображается нормально.

Comment: libzip тут не причем. она просто разжимает файл и отдает вам как есть. А файл - это просто набор байт. За то как эти самые байты выглядят на экране отвечает кодировка.Русский язык бывает в кодировках UTF8, cp1251, cp1252, koi8-r и еще нескольких экзотических. Для вывода файла на экран сначала надо узнать в какой он кодировке и перевести в ту кодировку которая у вас на экране или кодировку экрана привести к той, которая в файле...

Comment: По ссылке выше про язык консоли как раз говорится про приведение экран к требуемой кодировке. Если у вас сейчас cout выводит строку правильно, это лишь значит, что строка в исходном коде вашей программы набрана в той же кодировке, что и на консоли. А вот в файле в архиве кодировка другая. И кстати однозначного способа определения кодировке, кроме статистического анализа текста не существует, она должна быть известна заранее. Не зря текстовые редакторы позволяют просматривать файлы выбирая кодировку вручную

Comment: Понятно, я тогда пошел определять кодировку

Comment: Поменял кодировку txt файла на ANSI, теперь всё работает

Comment: по кодировке выше - это utf-8. Значит, либо выставляйте подходящую кодировку в консоли, либо перекодируйте в кодировку Вашей системы