# Как сделать правильный вывод string переменной?

Tags: c++, строки

Из-за этой ошибки не могу работать с переменной: не могу сравнить ее (if (command == "ПОВТОРИТЬ") ), не могу вывести нормально если сам ввел её. Как исправить?

[image: код]

[image: результат]

Сам код -

```
void main (){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    wcout.imbue(locale(".1251"));
    wcin.imbue(locale(".866"));


    cout << "Введи имя" << endl;

    string s;
    getline(cin, s);
    cout << s;
}
```

Comment: Исправить? Ввести код и результат не ссылками на картинки, и не картинками, а, согласно традициям и правилам ruSO, текстом прямо в вопросе.

Comment: изменил извиняюсь

Comment: вы сами поставили  разные кодировки в wcout и wcin. Чего вы ожидали? Автоконвертации?

Comment: С этим вопросом ознакомились: [Русский язык в консоли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/459154)?