# Как вывести на экран utf16

Tags: c++, windows, кодировка

Возможно ли отобразить символы UTF-16 в Windows'кой консоли, чтобы можно было именно емоджы выводить. Слышал, есть `std::u16string`, но как эго вывести на экран? Там хранится символ `''`.

Comment: `std::wcout` and `std::wstring`

Comment: Тут на сайте есть большой вопрос про кириллицу и в целом юникод в консоли: [Русский язык в консоли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/459154). Начните с него. Если описанные там варианты не работают, то уточните вопрос, что и как делали, и что получилось в итоге.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо

Comment: Смотрите, я прописал вот это - `_setmode(_fileno(stderr), _O_U16TEXT);` вывел через `wcout` но все равно `''` не выводится. Шрифт поменял на подходящий.

Comment: не знаю почему так, но `_O_U16TEXT`  сам о себе говорит. utf16!

Comment: Дефолтный терминал винды не умеет эмодзи. Попробуйте https://github.com/microsoft/terminal

Comment: @Alexey Ten интересно. Я скачал zip-архивом. Вопрос: а что дальше?

Comment: Эм, может лучше readme почитать сначала?

Comment: спасибо, прочитаю

Comment: кстати, я нашел Windows Terminal в Microsoft Store

Comment: Возможно, стоит там скачать?

Comment: Вы всё ещё не прочитали ридми? https://github.com/microsoft/terminal#microsoft-store-recommended

Comment: Install the Windows Terminal from the Microsoft Store. Понял, так и сделал

Comment: Теперь осталось подключить терминал к VS

Comment: ну а это совсем другой вопрос как сделать так, чтобы запускалось не с консоли обычной, а с Windows Terminal. Задаю эго!