# Кодировака в TERMINAL VS Code //  error: ==  РїРѕРјРёР»РєР°: ==  РѕС€РёР±РєР°:

Tags: кодировка, консоль, visual-studio-code, компиляция, gcc

При ошибке компиляции TERMINAL пишет:

*// Язык системы украинский*

> РїРѕРјРёР»РєР°: РЅРµРєРѕСЂРµРєС‚РЅРёР№ СЃСѓС„С–РєСЃ "f" Сѓ С†С–Р»С–Р№ РєРѕРЅСЃС‚Р°РЅС‚С–

*//Язык системы русский*

> РѕС€РёР±РєР°: РЅРµРІРµСЂРЅС‹Р№ СЃСѓС„С„РёРєСЃ В«fВ» РІ С†РµР»РѕС‡РёСЃР»РµРЅРЅРѕР№ РєРѕРЅСЃС‚Р°РЅС‚Рµ

*//Язык системы английский*

> error: invalid suffix "f" on integer constant

Один раз случайно что-то с интернета скопировал в терминал и заработало правильно.
То есть ошибку написал на украинском вместо иероглифов.
Работало корректно до перезагрузки.
Теперь снова иероглифы.

---

Сама программа без проблем выводит кириллицу. `SetConsoleCP(1251);` `SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);`. Проблема не в коде, а в выводе текста ошибки компилятора.

---

P.S.

Ответ: так переходи на язык системы английский. // Спасибо уже перешёл, но все равно хочу понимать как это исправить.

---

Ответ: поменяй кодировку на "CP866" или "windows-1251". // Не помогает. Результат: иероглифы другие. Менял следующими командами:

`[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("cp866")`

`[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("utf-8")`

`[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("Unicode")`

`[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("windows-1251")`

`chcp 1251`

`chcp 866`

`chcp 65001`

---

Ответ: Найди в истории браузера сайт с которого ты находил правильную команду и повтори. // Ага, уже десятки раз так делал, но увы не могу найти и вспомнить что именно я копировал. Сайтов было немало.

---

[image: РїРѕРјРёР»РєР°: РЅРµРєРѕСЂРµРєС‚РЅРёР№ СЃСѓС„С–РєСЃ "f" Сѓ С†С–Р»С–Р№ РєРѕРЅСЃС‚Р°РЅС‚С–]

[image: error: invalid suffix "f" on integer constant]

Comment: Это не 1251, а utf-8, который отображается в консоли с кодировкой 1251. `chcp 65001` должно работать

Comment: Методом наукового тику "відремонтував".
Спочатку пишемо в Terminal:

`chcp 1251`

, а потім:

`[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("utf-8")`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Русский язык в консоли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/%d0%a0%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8)