# Исправление проблем с кодировкой в Sublime Text при выводе в cmd

Tags: c++, cmd, sublime-text, mingw

В Sublime Text 3, программируя на C++, долго мучилась с выводом кириллицы в cmd. Оказалось, что это проблема консоли. Смена шрифта с Consolas на Lucida Console не помогла. Получилось решить изменением кодовой страницы со стандартной 866 (DOC) на 65001 (UTF-8) в коде, до начала выполнения программы с элементами вывода на кириллице:`std::system("chcp 65001");`
Как это сделать перманентно не знаю, оно и не нужно, пускай за счёт такого "костыля" повышается совместимость:)  В Code::Blocks такой проблемы нет, вывод кириллицы работает нормально "из коробки". Вывод кириллицы заработал, но вот новая проблема: Если первый символ в строке - кириллический, то вместо него показывается крякозябра, а весь следующий текст - нормально:
[image: Консоль]

Если строка начинается с цифры, латиницы, пробела, проблемы нет:

[image: Консоль]

[image: Консоль]

[image: Консоль]

Собственно, как решить проблему с неправильным выводом первого символа?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/459154/195342

Comment: ¿При чем тут Sublime Text?