# Как разобраться с вводом?

Tags: c++, ввод

```
   int a;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Место проживания (Дома, Общежитие, Съёмное жильё):";
    string residence;
    cin.get();
    getline(cin, residence);
    cout << residence << endl;
    while (residence != "Дома" || residence != "Общежитие" || residence != "Съёмное жильё") {
        cout << "Введите корректное место жительства: " << endl;
        getline(cin, residence);
    }
    int average_score;
    cin >> average_score;
```

Вроде учел что после чтения числа a надо отбросить перевод строки, чтобы можно было работать с getline. Почему после ввода переменной residence программа перестает реагировать на остальное?
Как исправить?

Comment: Условие в цикле `while` всегда истинно. Вероятно хотели использовать оператор `&&`...

Comment: Точно! Но проблема всё та же( Почему она не выводит residence после ввода?

Comment: После первого ввода (тот, что перед циклом) выводит. Ну а в цикле и после него Вы её и не выводите.

Comment: [Выводит](https://ideone.com/Jnjb8t). Добавьте больше подробностей в вопрос: входные/выходные данные (что ввели и что ожидаете получить) + чем/как компилируете (может у вас [проблемы с кириллицей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/459154)).

Comment: вот полный код: https://pastebin.com/Ver23y7e

Comment: начиная с 175 строки

Comment: Так там в цикле ещё есть `cin.get()`. `getline` сьедает символ новой строки. `cin.get()` там вроде как не нужен.

Comment: `начиная с 175 строки` [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).