# Вывести буквы в алфавитном порядке, не выводит русские символы

Tags: c++

Не могу вывести русские символы, англ выводит нормально:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
  char text[80];
  int i;
  int mas[256];
  cin.getline(text, 80, '\n'); // читаем текст
  for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    mas[i] = 0; // пока нет никаких символов
  for (i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++) //идем по тексту
    mas[(int)text[i]]++; // увеличиваем элемент массива с индексом, равным коду символа

  for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) // выводим символы
    if (mas[i] > 0) cout << (char)i << endl;

  _getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вероятно `char` знаковый, и кириллица кодируется отрицательными значениями. Попробуйте заменить `(int)text[i]` на `(unsigned char)text[i]`...

Comment: @wololo да, теперь когда пишу русские буквы начинают выводиться знаки, но выводятся крякозябры вместо русских букв теперь :/

Comment: [Русский язык в консоли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/459154).

Comment: @wololo да, это то что надо. Спасибо вам большое!