# Почему не удается выполнить ввод и вывод переменных заданных типов

Tags: c

Нужно ввести и вывести следующие переменные: ’E’; ’Меня зовут <фамилия и имя>’; 727, –968; 374.652,
–776.23; 108.
Корректно выводятся только E, 727, -968. Что нужно исправить, чтобы все переменные выводились правильно?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU");
    char g;
    char a[20], b[20];
    float f, e;
    int c, d, h;

    scanf_s("%c", &g);
    printf("%c \n", g);

    scanf_s("%s %s", &a, &b);
    printf("Меня зовут %s %s \n", a, b);
   
    scanf_s("%d", &c);
    printf("%d \n", c);

    scanf_s("%d", &d);
    printf("%d \n", d);

    scanf_s("%f", &f);
    printf("%.3f \n", f);

    scanf_s("%f", &e);
    printf("%.2f \n", e);

    scanf_s("%d", &h);
    printf("%d \n", h);

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, `scanf_s` хочет еще и размер данных. Так что нужны

```
scanf_s("%c", &g,1);

scanf_s("%s %s", a, 20, b, 20);
```

А для верного ввода-вывода чисел с плавающей точкой, раз уж вы объявили локаль "ru", надо использовать в таких числах не точку, а запятую...

Comment: Все работает, кроме вывода имени. Там же выводятся какие то каракули.

Comment: А вот насчет каракулей вам сюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/459154/195342