# Кракозябры в консоли Clion на Windows 10

Tags: c++, кодировка, windows-10, utf-8, clion

```
#include <cstdio>


int main() {
    (void)std::puts("привет ");
}
```

Установил CLion на Windows 10. Поставил encoding для исходника UTF-8. Всё равно печатает как в консоли IDE, так и в cmd:

> ╨┐╤А╨╕╨▓╨╡╤В ЁЯШК

Что делать, чтобы напечатало правильно? Без изменения исходников.

P.S.: Ответы из ["дубликата"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/459154/497885) не работают, в cmd стоит Consolas. В настройках IDE поставил везде UTF-8 и шрифты от Jetbrains. Остальные ответы про MSVS или требуют изменения исходников.

Comment: Так используйте родную кодировку UTF-16. А если уж зачем-то приспичело UTF-8, то переключайте кодировку консоли или ставьте стороннюю консоль, тот же  Windows Terminal например.

Comment: @user7860670 Settings->Console->Default Encoding стоит UTF-8

Answer (score -1):

Если ты хочешь русский язык в консоли то:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    cout << "Приветт!!!";

    system("pause");
    return 1;
}
```