# UTF-8 и C++, полноценная работа с различными языками в консольной программе

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, cmd

я новичок в с++ и у меня проблема с обработкой строк в unicode (далее в коде будут греческие и русские символы). Требуется считать данные с клавиатуры, записать в переменную и вывести в файл в utf-8, после считать. В гугле подробностей не нашел.

Параметры проекта:

- IDE = VS2019
- Набор под платформу vs2015 v140
- Проект = консольное приложение
- в свойствах проекта = использовать Юникод
- в свойствах консоли = текст: Lucida Console, кодировка: 65001(UTF-8)

Прикладываю отдельные части кода:

**1) код обработки ввода с клавиатуры (повторяется для имени и фамилии)**
*при дебаге в переменных 'str' 'strU' появляются кракозябры типо 0x00f436f0 L"Андрей\r\nôﺀó"*

```
HANDLE out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
HANDLE in = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
const size_t MAX_NUMBERS_OF_CHARS = 128;
wchar_t* str = (wchar_t*)calloc(MAX_NUMBERS_OF_CHARS, sizeof(wchar_t)); //для введенных символов
unsigned long entered_numbers_of_chars;

static std::wstring resourceString = L"\nEnter your name >>\n";
WriteConsoleW(out, resourceString.c_str(), resourceString.size(), NULL, NULL);
if (ReadConsoleW(in, str, MAX_NUMBERS_OF_CHARS, &entered_numbers_of_chars, NULL) == 0) {
    std::wcout << "ERROR: %ld", GetLastError();
}

// здесь удаляю '\r\n' из ввода
realloc(str, (entered_numbers_of_chars*sizeof(wchar_t))+1);    // ужимаю str в размер ввода из 128б
size_t strLen = wcslen(str);   // длина строки ввода = 'entered_numbers_of_chars'
size_t strLenU = strLen-2;     // длина строки без '\r\n'
wchar_t* strU = (wchar_t*)calloc(strLenU+1, sizeof(wchar_t));       //выделяю место под новую строку
wcsncpy(strU, str, strLenU);    // копирую введенную строку в новую без '\r\n'
wdata.name = strU;        // добавляю в структуру где хранятся данные (код структуры ниже)

//очищаю переменные перед следующим вводом -> фамилия
memset(str, 0, (entered_numbers_of_chars*sizeof(wchar_t)) + 1);
memset(strU, 0, (strLenU*sizeof(wchar_t)) + 1);

static std::wstring loginString = L"\nEnter your surname >>\n";
WriteConsoleW(out, loginString.c_str(), loginString.size(), NULL, NULL);
if (ReadConsoleW(in, str, MAX_NUMBERS_OF_CHARS, &entered_numbers_of_chars, NULL) == 0) {
    std::wcout << "ERROR: %ld", GetLastError();
}
realloc(str, (entered_numbers_of_chars*sizeof(wchar_t)) + 1);
strLen = wcslen(str);
strLenU = strLen - 2;
realloc(strU, (strLenU*sizeof(wchar_t)) + 1);
wcsncpy(strU, str, strLenU);
wdata.surname = strU;
            
memset(str, 0, (entered_numbers_of_chars*sizeof(wchar_t)) + 1);
memset(strU, 0, (strLenU*sizeof(wchar_t)) + 1);
```

Так же, при попытке очистить переменные str и strU через free() получаю ошибку

**2) код записи, отваливается на 3 строке '<<', с правильным кодом записи и чтении из файла затрудняюсь, подскажите**

```
 std::wofstream io_file;                  //создаем поток 
 io_file.open(dirPath, std::ios::app);  // открываем файл для записи в конец
 io_file << wdata.stResource << strSep << wdata.stLogin << strSep << wdata.stCyphPassword << strSep << strSep;
```

**3) код структуры wdata**

```
struct Credentials
{
    std::wstring name;
    std::wstring surname;
};
```

Comment: Посмотрите [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/459154/195342).

Comment: Странно, вроде как четко хотите задействовать utf-8, однако в коде нигде его использовать даже не пытаетесь. ¿Вы же в курсе, что `wchar_t` и большинство функций WinAPI работают в кодировке UTF-16, да? Кроме того, не стоит мешать вывод в консоль посредством WinAPI (`WriteConsoleW`) и средствами С++ (`cout`).

Comment: @user7860670 если есть понимание - поделитесь пожалуйста кодом?

Comment: Для того чтобы ввести текст из консоли и записать его в файл не нужна никакая специальная обработка. Все делается через обычные байтовые потоки вывода: `cin >> name;`, `f << name;`. `f` - типа `ofstream`. Utf-8 специально разработан так чтобы программы для работы с байтовыми потоками его нормально через себя пропускали. Удаление символов `\n`, `\r` также будет обработано правильно.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Наоборот же - программы, разработанные для работы с UTF-8 могут нормально работать с однобайтовым ASCII.

Comment: @user7860670, это правда. Но также правда, что utf-8 - поток байтов, которые управляются теми же символами что ASCII строки. Если вы разбиваете текст на строки или слова и склеиваете их обратно, или выполняете поиски и замены, то программа написанная для ASCII нормально обработает UTF-8. Трудности начинаются с момента, когда вам надо разбивать строку на символы (а эти символы многобайтовые).

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy в данном случае, обычные инструкции типа cin / ofstream / ... не работают, русские-греческие и пр. символы ими не обрабатываются, в файл записывается мешанина.

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь. Они обрабатываются нормально: если прочитали байты и эти же байты записали, что может испортиться? Покажите, конкретный пример, обсудим.