# Как в консольном приложении вывести символы ? C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Короче, я делаю программу, и решил заменить логотип со стандартных символов: # _ $ на чтото более крутое.
Нашел где можно сделать такой логотип, дальше сделал его, вставил в программу, и выводится вот это:
[image: Visual C++ Program]Я если что поставил кодировку UTF-8.

Символы:

░█████╗░██████╗░████████╗██╗░██████╗██╗░░██╗░█████╗░██████╗░██████╗░
██╔══██╗██╔══██╗╚══██╔══╝██║██╔════╝██║░░██║██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔══██╗
██║░░██║██████╔╝░░░██║░░░██║╚█████╗░███████║███████║██████╔╝██████╔╝
██║░░██║██╔═══╝░░░░██║░░░██║░╚═══██╗██╔══██║██╔══██║██╔══██╗██╔═══╝░
╚█████╔╝██║░░░░░░░░██║░░░██║██████╔╝██║░░██║██║░░██║██║░░██║██║░░░░░
░╚════╝░╚═╝░░░░░░░░╚═╝░░░╚═╝╚═════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚═╝░░╚═╝╚═╝░░╚═╝╚═╝░░░░░

Comment: Исходя из текста который я вижу у вас - кодировка окна консоли у вас CP866 а выводите в нее вы utf8...  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/Русский-язык-в-консоли

Comment: Чтото мне лучше не стало после того как я поставил там русский язык. Текст изменился на другой, но всеравно не то что мне нужно, и колонки чёт издавать странный звук начали

Comment: Второй ответ по ссылке, не первый, первый вам даст смену кодировки на CP1251 а не на искомый UTF8, смотрите внимательно весь ответ (_wsetlocale)