# Некорректная работа условных операторов

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Коллеги, добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста, почему я вписываю значение как в одном из условий, но мне выдает else?

```
    #include <iostream>

class Human 
{
public:
    std::string name;
    std::string sex;
    std::string colorofhair;
    std::string colorofskin;
    int age;
    int weight;
    int heigth;
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

    Human firstHuman;

    firstHuman.name = "Андрей";
    firstHuman.age = 21;
    firstHuman.sex = "Мужчина";
    firstHuman.colorofhair = "Чёрный";
    firstHuman.colorofskin = "Белый";
    firstHuman.weight = 67;
    firstHuman.heigth = 185;

    while (true)
    {
        std::string value;
        std::cout << "Введите свойство, которое вы хотите узнать?: ";
        std::cin >> value;

        if (value == "Имя")
        {
            std::cout << "Имя человека: " << firstHuman.name << std::endl;
        }
        else if (value == "Вес")
        {
            std::cout << "Возраст человека: " << firstHuman.age << std::endl;
        }
        else if (value == "Пол")
        {
            std::cout << "Пол человека: " << firstHuman.sex << std::endl;
        }
        else if (value == "Цвет волос")
        {
            std::cout << "Цвет волос человека: " << firstHuman.colorofhair << std::endl;
        }
        else if (value == "Цвет кожи")
        {
            std::cout << "Цвет кожи человека: " << firstHuman.colorofhair << std::endl;
        }
        else if (value == "Вес")
        {
            std::cout << "Вес человека: " << firstHuman.weight << std::endl;
        }
        else if (value == "Рост")
        {
            std::cout << "Рост человека: " << firstHuman.height << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "К сожалению такого свойства у этого человека нет." << std::endl;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Подозреваю, что проблемы с русским и кодировками... Посмотрите здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/459154/195342

Comment: @Harry Всё верно, попробовал на английском языке - всё работает. Пожалуй я дождусь какого то универсального решения, потому что всё что я прочитал по ссылке - работающее наполовину.

Comment: @Harry Спасибо Вам, что активно и оперативно помогаете таким новичкам как я)