# Проблемы с чтением с файла русских букв

Tags: c++

Пробовал читать с файла русские буквы. Вот в чем дело. Когда программа считывает файлы то, через debug можно заметить что слово с файла он смог увидеть
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда, я пытаюсь вывести в консоль то выходит проблема в виде непонятных символов
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кодировка консоли стоит 1251. Если писать строки или символы на русском в консоль и их вывести то все ок.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал менять чтение файла на wifstream, это не помогло. Так же кодировка самого файла UTF-8, я пытался сменить ее на ANSI, но Windows возвращал обратно UTF-8. Может кто подсказать, как прочитать файл с русскими символами? Еще пробовал wchar_t, но там была ошибка: Неопознанные символы.

Вот код:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    
    char text[50];
    string a;
    ifstream file("text.txt");
    if (!file.is_open())
        cout << "Error: File is not found!!!" << endl;
    else
    {
        file >> text;
        cout << text << endl;
        
        cin >> a;
        cout << a;
    }
    return 0;
```

P.S. хватит ставить мне ссылку на этот вопрос и закрывать мой вопрос. Я пробовал делать то что  там написано. Не помогло никак.  Да и вопросы отличаются. Я про эту ссылку [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/Русский-язык-в-консоли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8)
Еще раз, она мне не помогла. Тут совсем другой вопрос.

Comment: Ну первая строка у Вас явно utf-8 кодировка, а две других cp1251

Comment: А как вы пытались сменить кодировку файла?

Comment: `setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);` - не делайте так

Comment: @needKVAS Первый способ сохранить как в блокнот. Не сработало. Использовал Notepad++ и там пытался перекодировать, то же не вышло.

Comment: @user7860670 я понимаю, но без них были бы такие же символы. как первая строка с файла.

Comment: @Виктор ну как бы да. Я же и хочу чтобы и верхняя была в той кодировке. Дело в том, что в файл стоит в utf-8 и из-за этого такой текст. Я поэтому и прошу подсказать способ, как с файла получить русские буквы и вывести и х так же.

Comment: @kanejons2 Проверять кодировку у строки и перекодировать в cp1251 перед отображением

Comment: @Виктор да я пробовал. Тогда просто пустое значение выходит

Comment: @user7860670 могли бы подсказать как сделать, чтобы выводить с файла текст на русском?

Comment: Следует либо сделать так, чтобы в файле и в консоли была одинаковая кодировка, либо преобразовывать кодировку текста после чтения из файла в кодировку консоли (для этого можно взять библиотеку ICU или iconv).