# filesystem::directory_iterator и кириллица

Tags: c++, файловая-система, кириллица

Продолжение вопроса [Ошибка при компиляции - error_code (boost::filesystem::directory_iterator)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1498592/543696), но пробую решить по другому.

Посоветовали всё перевести в wstring.

**Изменено 2:**

Изменил точку входа, ошибка пропала.

Пробую решить методом: [Русский язык в консоли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/%d0%a0%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <filesystem>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

using namespace std;



class Find {

private:

wstring null = L"?";

wstring findFile_ (wstring name, wstring path) {
    wcout << name << "  " << path << endl;

    wstring temp;
    error_code ec;
wcout << "1" << endl;
    for (auto& file : filesystem::directory_iterator(name, ec)) {
wcout << "2" << endl;
        temp = file.path().wstring();
        wcout << temp << endl;
        if (filesystem::is_directory(file)) {
            wstring find = findFile_(name, temp);
            if (find != null) return find;
        } 
        if (name == temp.substr(temp.find_last_of(L"\\") + 1, wstring::npos)) return file.path().wstring();
    }
wcout << "3" << endl;
    return null;
}



public:
wstring findFile (wstring name) {
    DWORD drives = GetLogicalDrives();
    char diskName;
    wstring disk;
    wstring ret;
    for (unsigned char i = 0; i < 32; i++) {

        if (drives & (1 << i)) {
            diskName = 'A' + i;
            disk.clear();
            disk.push_back(diskName);
            disk += L":\\";
            ret = findFile_(name, disk);
            if (ret != null) return ret;   
        }
    }
    return null;
}

};


int main () {

    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin),  _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stderr), _O_U16TEXT);

    wcout << L"Unicode -- English -- Русский -- Ελληνικά -- Español -- Українська." << endl;
    

    Find f;
    wcout << f.findFile(L"Aboba.txt") << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Теперь другая проблема:

Не срабатывает цикл

```cpp
for (auto& file : filesystem::directory_iterator(name, ec)) {
wcout << "2" << endl;
        temp = file.path().wstring();
        wcout << temp << endl;
        if (filesystem::is_directory(file)) {
            wstring find = findFile_(name, temp);
            if (find != null) return find;
        } 
        if (name == temp.substr(temp.find_last_of(L"\\") + 1, wstring::npos)) return file.path().wstring();
    }
```

Выводит в консоль:

```
Unicode -- English -- Русский -- Ελληνικά -- Español -- Українська.
Aboba.txt  C:\
1
3
Aboba.txt  F:\
1
3
?
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```

**Думаю, причина в `name`, но не знаю, как можно это проверить и исправить**

Comment: `что вообще в коде не так` - зачем-то устанавливается code page 65001 (UTF-8), а вывод идет через wcout (UCS-2).

Comment: **зачем-то устанавливается code page 65001 (UTF-8)**

Убрал. Теперь пишет кракозябры:

`
1
1
1
��� �த������� ������ ���� ������� . . . 
`

Comment: @user7860670 Я не против закрытия вопроса, как дубля — но не как дубля для "русского в консоли", а "[Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536546/195342)", потому что ТС задал именно этот вопрос!

Comment: @Harry А ОП поменял вопрос на совсем другой. Причем он зачем-то поменял в своем коде точку входа, отсюда и проблема вылезла.

Comment: Основная проблема - код не умеет работать с кириллицей. Пытаюсь её решить, но появляются новые проблемы. Не создавать же под каждую проблему (которую, возможно, смогу сам решить) новую тему, ведь суть одна - код не работает с кириллицей.

Comment: Нет, для каждой новой проблемы следует создавать новую тему и заново составить [mcve]. Тут не бюро по отладке чужого кода. А прежде, чем бездумно копипастить код из того ответа, вам стоило прочитать его целиком (а заодно и документацию ко всем использованным там функциям) и разобраться, что у вас было не так.

Comment: @user7860670 Все, вопрос снят (и его, и мой :)) — не обратил внимания, что он правлен. Приношу извинения.