# в консоли vs code на языке C++ вместо русского слова выводит только букву Р

Tags: c++

**написал программу на С++ для простого вывода текста на русском**

, но до того как ставить галочку на использовании Юникод для, выводили каракули, но поставив галочку выдает одну букву Р, иногда если изменить значение вывода то она меняется на другое,

извините если объяснил невнятно

```
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;  
  
int main()  
{  
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");  
    cout << "здарово" << endl;  
}
```

Comment: дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9). скорее всего: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/459154/178576