# Язык отображения в консоли

Tags: c++, windows, ubuntu, stl

Пишу программу клиент-серверное приложение, особенность состоит в том, что сервер будет на Ubuntu, а клиент будет работать в Windows. И столкнулся с знаменитой проблемой с языком в консоли. На первых парах думал, что устранить данную проблему элементарно, но чем больше пытался устранить её, тем меньше у меня что-то получалось. Сразу оговорюсь, что собираю проект из под Ubuntu при помощи компилятора x86_64-w64-mingw32.

Что я попробовал: пробовал установить `std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` результат изменился, но чуть попозже скажу, что изменилось. Пробовал `SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); SetConsoleCP(1251);` писать, результат тоже изменился, пробовал установить широкии символы и напечатать их, но программа в принципе отказывалась их печатать:
`std::locale::global(std::locale("")); // Устанавливаем текущую локализацию std::wcout.imbue(std::locale()); // Устанавливаем локализацию для wcout wcout << L"Привет" << endl;`

Вот результат: без установки локали:

> Hello world! ╨б╨╛╨║╨╡╤В ╨╕╨╜╨╕╤Ж╨╕╨░╨╗╨╕╨╖╨╕╤А╨╛╨▓╨░╨╜ ╨б╨╛╨║╨╡╤В
> ╤Б╨╛╨╖╨┤╨░╨╜

С установкой локали:

> Hello world! РЎРѕРєРµС‚ РёРЅРёС†РёР°Р»РёР·РёСЂРѕРІР°РЅ РЎРѕРєРµС‚
> СЃРѕР·РґР°РЅ

Есть ли тут эксперты по работам со строками и их локализацией? Кто может, подскажите пожалйста. Работаю в Visual Studio Code.
По поводу этого вопроса:[Русский язык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8), мне эта информация не помогла, я уже написал выше, что я пробовал.

Comment: в последнем случае у вас где-то там происходит лишняя перекодировка из cp1251 в utf8 текста, который и так представлен в кодировке utf8: `$ echo РЎРѕРєРµС‚ | iconv -f utf8 -t cp1251` → `Сокет`