# Установка локали для wcin

Tags: c++, locale

Создаю клиент-серверное приложение, мини мессанджр. И пытаюсь передать русские символы из Windows в Ubuntu. Постоянно приходили какие-то кракозябры и не мог понять в чем же дело, даже распечатал коды символов в Windows и Ubuntu, получив при этом одинаковый результыт, короче, выяснилось что команда `wcin` установлена в другой локали, посмотрел в интернете как устанавливается для `wcin` локаль, что-то вроде: `std::wcin.imbue(std::locale(""));` но постоянно устанавливается локаль `C` которая конечно же ничего не отображает корректно, вместо кода 'A'=410, печатается код = 402. Я пытался сделать следующее:

```
std::string local = std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
std::wcout.imbue(std::locale(local));
std::wcin.imbue(std::locale(local));
```

но получаю ошибку: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
чтобы я туда не писал(".1251","rus",".utf8" и т.д. ) На все один ответ, не знаю что мне делать с этим. Очень нужно, чтобы кто-то помог установить локаль для wcin.

Comment: Это похоже на проблему XY. При использовании wcin на Windows в установки локали необходимость отсутствует. Ну а на linux отсутствует необходимость в wcin.

Comment: Ничего не понял, мне нужно печатать строку и отправлять её, она в кривой локали заносится в переменную и отправляется соответственно тоже.

Comment: [Русский язык в консоли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/%d0%a0%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8) - вот решение для Windows. Как видите, никакой локали там не фигурирует. Ну а на linux отсутствует необходимость в wcin, как я уже писал выше.

Comment: Я жалуюсь не на русский язык в консоли, он устанавливается std::string local = std::setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); Я  жалуюсь именно на ввод с клавиатуры wcin, что он вводит символы с другой коддировкой

Comment: `std::string local = std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` не устанавливает русский язык в консоли...

Comment: извиняюсь, ваш ответ выше мне помог, спасибо большое