# Почему если смотреть ASCII код выбранного элемента через заданную строку, то выводится одно значение, а если вводить число через консоль, то другое?

Tags: c

Вот код. Для элемента к, допустим, выводится код -22, но если я ввожу к в консоль, то уже к соответствует значение - 86. Как исправить эту ошибку, чтобы коды соответствовали?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    char alp[100] = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьюэя";
    for (int i = 0; i < 33; i++){
        printf("%c - %d\n", alp[i], (int)(alp[i]));
    }
    char str[100];
    gets(str);
    puts(str);
    printf("%d", (int)(str[0]));
}
```

[image: ****]

Comment: [Всё прочли, и ничего не помогло?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/459154)

Comment: В винде у вас кодировка в программе [cp1251](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251), а в вводе-выводе консоли [cp866](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP866) (однако, если вызвать программу из консоли и передать ей аргументы командной строки (argv[] в main), то эти строки будут в cp1251) (вот такие чудеса от Б. Гейтса) (дальше думайте сами стоит ли вам вообще учиться в ней программить)

Comment: @avp если бы в **выводе** была cp866, тогда вместо алфавита вывелись бы кракозябры

Comment: @andreymal, а они и вывелись бы, просто `setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");` это частично исправляет.

Comment: Небольшой оффтоп: буквы нумеруются положительными числами, так лучше бы использовать беззнаковые