# При использовании setlocale не выводится цветной текст C++

Tags: c++, c, unicode

```
using namespace std;

int main() {


    // Коды цветов
    const char* colors[] = {
      "\u001B[31m", // Красный
      "\u001B[32m", // Зеленый
      "\u001B[33m", // Желтый
      "\u001B[34m", // Синий
      "\u001B[35m", // Маджента
      "\u001B[36m", // Голубой
    };

    // Печать радужного текста
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) { // уменьшаем до 6
        cout << colors[i] << "Привет радуга" << endl;
    }

    // Сброс цвета
    cout << "\u001B[0m" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Выводится какие-то кракозябры:

╧ЁштхЄ Ёрфєур

╧ЁштхЄ Ёрфєур

╧ЁштхЄ Ёрфєур

╧ЁштхЄ Ёрфєур

╧ЁштхЄ Ёрфєур

╧ЁштхЄ Ёрфєур

А если добавить setlocale

using namespace std;

int main() {
setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8");

```
// Коды цветов
const char* colors[] = {
  "\u001B[31m", // Красный
  "\u001B[32m", // Зеленый
  "\u001B[33m", // Желтый
  "\u001B[34m", // Синий
  "\u001B[35m", // Маджента
  "\u001B[36m", // Голубой
};

// Печать радужного текста
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) { // уменьшаем до 6
    cout << colors[i] << "Привет радуга" << endl;
}

// Сброс цвета
cout << "\u001B[0m" << endl;

return 0;
```

}

Выводится просто пустота [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то-есть текст как-бы выводится, но его почему-то не видно.

Почему так? И как это исправить ?

Comment: В первом варианте цветные крякозябры или нет?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Да

Comment: Судя по первому выводу `╧ЁштхЄ Ёрфєур`  у Вас файл в однобайтовой кодировке cp1251 (ANSI).  Эти константы в UTF-8 не выведутся. Попробуйте сохранить код в utf-8, может быть получится. А по поводу вывода русского вот тут полный разбор https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8.