Русский язык и cout в qt
У меня есть консольное приложение в Qt. Я хочу выводить русский текст в консоль через std::cout, но стандартный способ установки языка через setlocale не работает.
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

   setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
   std::cout << "привет мир" << std::endl;

   return a.exec();
}

Вывод приложения: РїСЂРёРІРµС‚ РјРёСЂ
Еще раз подчеркну мне нужен вывод именно с помощью std::cout. Если вы знаете как это исправить помогите.

а если убрать вот эту лишнюю перекодирвку: setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");?

Посмотрите вот этот вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8 Но идее там должно быть решение вашей проблемы.

Попробуйте поменять вывод и строки на широко символьные(wchar_t, wstring, wprintf, wcout)  там, где используется русский язык
